# mysql tables have two foreign keys from another same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table.

---

1. invoice
2. user

---

In user table I have

```
user_id
user_name
user_email    
user_address
```

In invoice table I have

```
invoice_id
invoice_to_user_id
invoice_by_user_id
invoice_date
```

In invoice table I have two foreign key from user table.
1. invoice_to_user_id
2. invoice_by_user_id

now I want to make single query that get the user info of both foreign keys.e.g,
1. invoice_to_user_name
2. invoice_to_user_email
3. invoice_to_user_address
4. invoice_by_user_name
5. invoice_by_user_email
6. invoice_by_user_address

Thanks In advance.

Comment: what you want as an output ?

Comment: Join the `user` table 2 times

Comment: can u show what u have done yet and whats ur result

Comment: select invoice.invoice_id,invoice.projects_id,invoice.invoice_status,user.user_name,projects.projects_title from invoice 
inner join user
on user.user_id=invoice.invoice_by
inner join projects on projects.projects_id=invoice.projects_id
where invoice.invoice_to=3 or invoice.invoice_by=3
order by invoice.invoice_date desc;<br><br>this query works for one user info only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the invoice table with the user table twice, once on invoice_to_user_id and then again on invoice_by_user_id, e.g.

```
SELECT
INV.invoice_id,
US1.user_name AS invoice_to_user_name,
US1.user_email AS invoice_to_user_email,
US1.user_address AS invoice_to_user_address,
US2.user_name AS invoice_by_user_name,
US2.user_email AS invoice_by_user_email,
US2.user_address AS invoice_by_user_address
FROM
[invoice] INV
INNER JOIN [user] US1 ON INV.invoice_to_user_id = US1.user_id
INNER JOIN [user] US2 ON INV.invoice_by_user_id = US2.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.user_name    AS invoice_to_user_name,
       t.user_email   AS invoice_to_user_email,
       t.user_address AS invoice_to_user_address,
       b.user_name    AS invoice_by_user_name,
       b.user_email   AS invoice_by_user_email,
       b.user_address AS invoice_by_user_address
FROM invoice i
LEFT JOIN user t ON t.user_id = i.invoice_to_user_id
LEFT JOIN user b ON b.user_id = i.invoice_by_user_id
```